# Add set(distinct elements) in rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to create following Json object

```
 {
    "name":"abc",
    "property1"=[2010, 2013, 2015],
    "property2"=["str1, "str2", str3"],
    "property3"=[true, false]
 }
```

property1, property2, property3 is basically an array but with distinct elements.
Currently I am creating through:

```
document.AddMember("property1", Value(kArrayType), allocator);
document.AddMember("property2", Value(kArrayType), allocator);
document.AddMember("property3", Value(kArrayType), allocator);
```

Then I iterate over the list and push the value in the object through:

```
for (auto& iter: object_info_list) {
    document["property1"].PushBack(iter->property1, allocator); //int value
    document["property2"].PushBack(iter->property2, allocator); // string value
    document["property3"].PushBack(iter->property3, allocator); // bool value
}
```

But the above statement pushes all the values (duplicates) as well. Is there a way to add distinct values only (like set in c++)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not make `list_of_working_years` as `std::set`?

Comment: @Wander3r updated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't have many data types. You will need to de-duplicate in the C++ data structure you are copying from.

E.g.

```
std::set<int> property1;
std::set<std::string> property2;
std::set<bool> property3;

for (auto& iter: object_info_list) {
    property1.insert(iter->property1);
    property2.insert(iter->property2);
    property3.insert(iter->property3);
}

for (auto val : property1) {
    document["property1"].PushBack(val, allocator);
}

for (auto val : property2) {
    document["property2"].PushBack(val, allocator);
}

for (auto val : property3) {
    document["property3"].PushBack(val, allocator);
}
```